# How do I show an associated value with a dropdown list item (after choosing it from the list)?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I am programming in ASP.NET, visual studio. I have a dropdown list created in HTML form. If I dropdown the list, it displays the record from associated column in the table. But what I want is to show the corresponding value / record with that list item.

For example in the table, I have column `id`, `productname` and `price`. After choosing a particular product name (from drop down list), the associated price with it must be displayed in front of it (in a label).

However, By default, I want the drop down list  to shows nothing in the beginning.

**UPDATE:**

Store.aspx:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        Welcome
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
       Products: <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" ></asp:DropDownList>
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [productdata]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

    &nbsp;Price:
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
         <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add to Cart" />
        <br />
        <br />
        Items in cart: <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>

        <br />
        <br />

        Total Price: <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label>

    </div>
    </form>
```

Store.aspx.cs:

```
    public partial class Store : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label3.Text = Request.QueryString["name"];//show welcome text
            String cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                using (SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(cs))
                {
                    SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand("Select id, productname, price from productdata", sc);
                    sc.Open();
                    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "productname";//show in the dropdown list
                    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "price"; //show in the label
                    DropDownList1.DataSource = sqlcom.ExecuteReader();
                    DropDownList1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
        protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlDataReader rd;
            using (SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand("Select id, productname, price from productdata where id=" + Convert.ToUInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue), sc);
                sc.Open();

                rd = sqlcom.ExecuteReader();
                if (rd.Read())
                {
                    Label1.Text = rd[2].ToString();
                }
                sc.Close();

            }

        }
 }
```

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[productdata] (
    [Id]          INT          NOT NULL,
    [productname] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [price]       FLOAT (53)   NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: It seems you are using sql server, but you tagged mysql, please update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Edit according to using `AutoPostBack=True` and `if (!IsPostBack)` in `Page_Load` thanks to `Arindam`:

For simply solution using postback event:

First you should add `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event for dropdownlist

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="GetPrice" AutoPostBack="true">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Then in code behind you just get selected value and fill to the label price

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Label3.Text = Request.QueryString["name"];//show welcome text
        String cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand("Select id, productname, price from productdata", sc);
            sc.Open();
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "productname";//show in the dropdown list
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "price"; //show in the label
            DropDownList1.DataSource = sqlcom.ExecuteReader();
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
protected void GetPrice(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
}
```

1. You have to use `AutoPostBack=True` so that when you change index of dropdownlist, it will trigger a postback to server so the function `GetPrice(...)` will be called.
2. Every time the page `postback`, it will call function `Page_Load(...)` first, so you must use propertive `IsPostBack` to check if **case1**_this is the first time the page is loaded, or **case2**_a postback event, and you only set the ddl datasource at **case1** because if you set datasource, by default the dropdownlist will **reset** to select first item in list.

When you go advance, you should consider using Javascript and Jquery to solve this, so the page will not load again like this postback solution.

And one more thing, you should name your controls well, don't make them default like that. It's one of [two hard things in programming](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html).

Comment: Pham X. Bach , thank, but unfortunately it doesn't do anything. see my update please.

Comment: Did you place the function `protected void GetPrice(.....` in your `Store.aspx.cs` code?

Comment: Pham X. Bach, yes, but after I build the project, error is gone. but it doesn't do what it is supposed to. I am going to update the code to show u,.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can but if not please use datatable and i am sure that work fine .if u not able do that just post I will give the correction.

Comment: Arindam , datatable? ok, I have updated the post with exactly what I have now.

Comment: ok, if you mean database table, I have it. I am fetching data from a database table.